# Sharing variables between Form and Header File in Visual C

Tags: c, winforms, visual-c++

I do not know how to share data between the form and another header file.
There is a problem with the variable input.
I do not know how I declare it to be accessible from the form. The main calculation is in other.h.
I want to set up a variable in form and send it to other.h, calculate and return the form.
How do I declare int input?

note:
The problem is the btnWrong

```
//   Form1.h 

#pragma once
    #include "other.h"


    namespace VariablesandDebugging {


        using namespace System;
        using namespace System::ComponentModel;
        using namespace System::Collections;
        using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
        using namespace System::Data;
        using namespace System::Drawing;

        /// <summary>
        /// Summary for Form1
        /// </summary>
        public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
        {
        public:
            Form1(void)
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                //
                //TODO: Add the constructor code here
                //
            }

        protected:
            /// <summary>
            /// Clean up any resources being used.
            /// </summary>
            ~Form1()
            {
                if (components)
                {
                    delete components;
                }
            }
    //private: System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox^ pictureBox1;
        private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  lblHeader1;
        private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  btnRight;
        private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  btnWrong;

        private:
            /// <summary>
            /// Required designer variable.
            /// </summary>
            System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

            //My variables
        private:
            int iInches;
            int iFeet;
            bool bConvertingToInches;//???
            int iConvertedInches;
            int iRozpeti;


    #pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
            /// <summary>
            /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
            /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
            /// </summary>
            void InitializeComponent(void)
            {
                this->btnRight = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
                this->btnWrong = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
                // 
                // btnConvert
                // 
                this->btnRight->Location = System::Drawing::Point(60, 60);
                this->btnRight->Text = L"In Form1";
                this->btnRight->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::btnRight_Click);
                this->Controls->Add(this->btnRight);
                // 
                // btnExit
                // 
                this->btnWrong->Location = System::Drawing::Point(60, 150);
                this->btnWrong->Text = L"In other.h";
                this->btnWrong->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::btnWrong_Click);
                this->Controls->Add(this->btnWrong);


            }
    #pragma endregion
    public: System::Void btnWrong_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
                getfavoritenumber2(a, b);
                MessageBox::Show(Convert::ToString(a));
                MessageBox::Show(Convert::ToString(b));
                }

    public: System::Void btnRight_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
                input = 10; 
                getfavoritenumber3(a, b, output);
                MessageBox::Show(Convert::ToString(a));
                MessageBox::Show(Convert::ToString(b));
                MessageBox::Show(Convert::ToString(output));
             }
        };
    }



//other.h

#ifndef _OTHER_H_
#define _OTHER_H_

int a;
int b;
int input;  

void getfavoritenumber2(int &a, int &b)
{
    a = 3;
    b = 6;
}

void getfavoritenumber3(int &a, int &b, int &output)
{
    a = 3;
    b = 6;
    output = input*input;
}

#endif
```

Thank you very much

Comment: @Dayalrai It must be `C with Classes` ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can use file scope static variables.

But this very old and bad idea, so consider global / extern